# How to align startIcon material ui icon at the center?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to keep the icon button center aligned, but something isn't working right. Adding  left: "0.5rem" to sx prop is pushing the button icon further. I'm trying not to use makeStyles to override the position. Any tip/direction would be helpful :)

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-tooltip-forked-c3v8ip?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to set it in you theme here is how you can do it so you don't have to do it in every Button component.

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  ...
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        startIcon: {
          margin: '0'
        },
      },
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try using style:**

```
<Stack direction="row" style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
  <Tooltip title="Delete">
    <Button sx={{ minWidth: 0 }} startIcon={<DeleteIcon />} />
  </Tooltip>
  <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
  <Tooltip title="Send">
    <Button sx={{ minWidth: 0 }} startIcon={<SendIcon />} />
  </Tooltip>
  <Tooltip title="Headset">
    <Button sx={{ minWidth: 0 }} startIcon={<HeadsetMicOutlined />} />
  </Tooltip>
  <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
</Stack>
```

Comment: This made the button elements to the center position, but not the icon to the center for that button. I assume the margin for the startIcon class is coming from the material-ui itself.

Comment: Hey mate. `<Button sx={{ "& .MuiButton-startIcon": { margin: "0px" }, minWidth:0 }} />` 

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your style override

```
components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        startIcon: ({ ownerState }) => ({
          ...(ownerState.children
            ? {}
            : {
                // if no button label, center icon (e.g mobile)
                marginRight: 0,
              }),
        }),
      },
    },
```